# Getting Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil while running VSTests with code coverage enabled

Tags: .net, azure-devops, vstest

I have a pipeline defined in azure devops that build the VS Solution and executes the VSTests. I have enabled the code coverage as well. However the VSTests fails with the message: `##[error]Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: Data collector caught an exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException': 'Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Cecil, Version=0.11.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. More details: ..`. I am not sure from where the `Mono.Cecil` reference is coming from.

Comment: Hi there, When you rebuilded and tested your solution with Visual Studio on local machine, was the issue reproducible and was it required to use and succeeded in downloading the assembly `Mono.Cecil`? Did you check in the files`.*proj` and `packages.config` of your projects if the package was referenced correctly or depended by other packages? If yes, did you observe the dependency was downloaded during pipeline `dotnet/nuget` restore step and copied to the expected output local for `VSTest`?

Comment: Yes, running VSTests locally succeeds. I did search for the package ```Mono.Cecil``` in my ```.csproj`` but was not able to find it. I turned on detailed logging in devops but was not able to find anything about the package.

Comment: Have you checked the local build directory and if the assembly was saved in the bin directory? I you add `Mono.Cecil` to your project, will the `VSTest` succeed after the packages is restored?

Comment: Yes, I did check the local bin directory of all my projects but couldn't find it.

Comment: If you add `Mono.Cecil` as a dependency to your project, will the `VSTest` succeed after the package is restored?